# unhandled rejection reqldrivererror: first argument to `run` must be an open connection

Tags: javascript, база-данных, rethinkdb

Возникла проблема... Rethinkdb не подключается к моей бд. Я может что-то и указал неправильно, но все делал через доки
Строчки, где есть rethink

````
  var connection = null;
  db.connect({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 28015,
    db: 'bot',
    password: 'Atljh338954'
}, function(err, conn) {
  if (err) throw err;
  connection = conn;
});```

    db.table('money').filter({userid: message.author.id}).insert(args[0]).run(connection, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
})
````